# How can I debug the indentation in this code?

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop

The objective is to analyse log from a folder and send email if certain keywords are present in the file. It should be running every 5 sec or so. 
The below code is functional. Only thing is it's not checking the condition set in the while loop and it's running infinitely. I assume its an issue with the indentation?

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import os
import time
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

Error_Suspects = ['Error', 'ERROR', 'Failed', 'Failure']


# Error_Suspects = ['failed']


def detect_suspects(file_path, word_list):
    with open(file_path) as LogFile:
        Summary = {word: [] for word in word_list}
        failure = ':'
        for num, line in enumerate(LogFile, start=1):
            for word in word_list:
                if word in line:
                    failure += '<li>' + line + '</li>'
    return failure


prev_file = None
prev_mtime = None
# Error_Suspects = ['Error', 'ERROR', 'Failed', 'Failure']

while True:

    files = os.listdir('.')
    latest_file = max(files, key=os.path.getmtime)

    if latest_file != prev_file or (latest_file == prev_file and prev_mtime != os.path.getmtime(latest_file)):
        Result = detect_suspects(latest_file, Error_Suspects)
        prev_file = latest_file
        prev_mtime = os.path.getmtime(latest_file)



    def py_mail(SUBJECT, BODY, TO, FROM):
        MESSAGE = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        MESSAGE['subject'] = SUBJECT
        MESSAGE['To'] = TO
        MESSAGE['From'] = FROM
        MESSAGE.preamble = """    """
        HTML_BODY = MIMEText(BODY, 'html')
        MESSAGE.attach(HTML_BODY)

        username = 'XXX'
        password = 'XXX'
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
        server.starttls()
        server.login(username, password)

        if __name__ == "__main__":
            server.set_debuglevel(1)
            server.sendmail(FROM, [TO], MESSAGE.as_string())
            server.quit()


    if Result != None:

        if __name__ == "__main__":
            """Executes if the script is run as main script (for testing purposes)"""

            email_content = """


           <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
         <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
         <title>Qlik Sense Alerts!</title>
          </head>


         <body bgcolor="#8d8e90">
         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#8d8e90">
         <tr>
        <td><table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center">


         <tr>
          <td align="center"><font style="font-family:'Myriad Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#68696a; font-size:36px; text-transform:uppercase"><strong>Qlik Sense Alerts!</strong></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center"><a href= "" target="_blank"><img src="http://us.analytics8.com/images/uploads/general/762/qlikmaps-2.png" alt="" width="598" height="249" border="0"/></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td width="7%"> </td>
                <td width="58%" align="left" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td> </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="95%"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                          <tr>
                            <td height="35" align="left" valign="middle" style="border-bottom:2px dotted #000000"><font style="font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; color:#000000; font-size:25px"><strong><em>Error Information</em></strong></font></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <!-- our content -->


                            <ul> Error List
                             """

            email_content += Result

            email_content += """
                        </ul>
                          </tr>


                        </table></td>
                        <td width="5%" style="border-right:2px dashed #95989a"> </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table></td>
                  </tr>
                </table></td>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center"><font style="font-family:'Myriad Pro', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#231f20; font-size:8px"><strong>IBM | <a href= "http://google.com" style="color:#010203; text-decoration:none">Coded_i04497l</a></strong></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> </td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
         </tr>
        </table>
       </body>
      </html>




         """

            TO = 'xxx.xx@gmail.com'
            FROM = 'XXX.XX@gmail.com'

            py_mail("Qlik Sense Alerts!", email_content, TO, FROM)

time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a debugging service.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: move the new function out of while loop and use a break

Comment: What did you expect with `while True` and no `break`? For one, the last line `time.sleep(5)` would make more sense if indented so it becomes part of the `while` loop body.

Comment: @augurar I am new to this community as well as programming.I will be learning my lessons!!

Comment: @bigbounty I have done it and after little trial and errors I could make it work..thanks!

Comment: @trincot the suggestion helped..thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of a commenter)*.

What did you expect with `while True` and no `break`? For one, the last line `time.sleep(5)` would make more sense if indented so it becomes part of the `while` loop body.